# try and catch with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, try-catch, internet-connection

I have a button that logs me out of Parse but if I try to log out without an internet connection the app crashes. So I tried to put everything in a try and catch but the app still crashes if I attempt to logout without an internet connection. Why is that?

```
try {
    Log.i("AppInfo", "button worked");

    ParseUser.logOut();

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.i("AppInfo", "catch was successful");

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: We can't know why your app crashes without the stacktrace

Comment: A few other points: a) It's often a bad practice to catch "Exception" - it's better to try to catch *specific* connections. b) If this is something that you expect to occur regularly I'd recommend explicitly checking for whether or not you have an internet connection before you attempt this. While using exceptions to handle control flow is slightly more idiomatically acceptable in Java than it is in some other languages like C# I still think that it's a bad practice - use "if" statements for ordinary cases and catch exceptions for exceptional cases.

Comment: One more point: since you're catching "exception" rather than the more specific exception that occurs when there's no connectivity, how do you know whether your error message Toast is correct?